Double Escaping in nginx's $ssl_client_s_dn
I have a client certificate which has non English characters in the subject, when I use the attribute $ssl_client_s_dn of ngx_http_ssl_module the value is escaped twice.
real value = "L=D'UNCONGÉ"
the \xC3 is encoded again to get \x5CC3 ,I need to avoid this
actual value = "L=D'UNCONG\x5CC3\x5C89"
expected value = "L=D'UNCONG\xC3\x89"
can someone please advise me on what I did wrong, How can I avoid this.

I don't understand how your expected value is supposed to occur. I understand the actual value occurring as there is an opening and closing double-quote, with an apostrophe (I assume apostrophe and not single-quote? right?) Pls update  with corrected values

No I meant the encoding of É in the certificate , I have updated the question too. In short  É should be encoded as xC3\x89 but the value I am getting in nginx when I access it with  $ssl_client_s_dn is \x5CC3\x5C89

Thanks for the clarification, I understood the double encoding part, but needed clarification on the confusing extra quote... thanks all good. Now let me ruminate on some actual answer...

There are many parts to this puzzle.
First, let me comment that the "Expected Value" you mention includes Hexadecimal numeric constants (format: \xHH). This would only be 'expected' where this is a default encoding.
Nginx itself uses most String Literals and Numeric Constants such as Hex, Octal or Unicode representations without an issue in configs; and the same when it reads Headers- so I was initially confused by the unusual format of this "double-escaping".
I checked the RFC regarding Cert Encoding of Distinguished Name (DN). There is a subtle difference in how the Cert String is formatted vs. something like double-encoded URL strings, but the diff is important.
Please Note the RFC and in particular Note the table of examples toward the end of section 5 and see "Quoted" values vs. UTF-8:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2253#section-5
The RFC states that Cert UTF-8 "É" (0xC389) when Quoted is \C3\89. Based on the Actual Value you have reported, this confirms => Nginx is reading a Quoted value from the Cert itself.
Then Nginx escapes the "\" in \C3\89 and this explains why it becomes \x5CC3\x5C89 as in your "Actual Value".
However, this unusual representation is (probably) limited to the Logs of Nginx itself -  depending on your configs it is probably not the actual value of $ssl_client_s_dn.
By default Nginx escapes strings in Logs but does not escape values in variables. Regarding the log format you can prevent escaping by adding an option to the log_format directive:
#find this in the http {} block of Nginx
# 'main' is just an example name
  log_format main ... # 'main' is a just a name, yours might be different

#make it so
  log_format main escape=none ... # keep your name, not 'main' 

Append the variable $ssl_client_s_dn to the appropriate place in the log_format value so that it can be checked. Study the Nginx Log Module if necessry to see how to do this https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html
If you are new to Nginx this may be a lot to unpack... so let me review the main points, and after careful consideration hopefully you can tailor the config correctly to suit the exact use-case:

This problem is implementation specific, meaning it does not have a generic solution. There isn't some simple fundamental issue here- it is a complex case of numerous dependent factors.

Preventing Escaped Logs will help you better understand the value you have received from the Cert; please ensure that you log at least $ssl_client_s_dn until you are sure everything is working as expected.

If some Proxy/Server/Service other than an End User sends the Client Cert to Nginx, keep in mind this is the chief Dependency - How they construct the Cert encoding determines how the Cert Subject DN will be read by Nginx.

Note this point alone could solve cases in which the Upstream is mangling the Header value- If you are sending the value of $ssl_client_s_dn to the App/Uptream in a Header, ensure that you DO NOT enclose it in quotes, because this does not need to be escaped for Nginx, and probably does not need to be escaped by the Upstream. If this is already done, then change it so that you DO enclose it in quotes. While I prefer the non-quoted method, this simple change could "fix" the issue for the App/Upstream:
 location /blah {
     ...
     #try this first, replacing X-Subject-DN with the correct Header name
     proxy_set_header X-Subject-DN $ssl_client_s_dn;

     #then try this, do not use both else duplicate Header
     proxy_set_header X-Subject-DN "$ssl_client_s_dn";
 }


I am making many assumptions. You might not forward the Cert Subject DN to another resource at all, you might only evaluate it in Nginx, you might have already updated log_format with escape=none, there are so many possible situations...


In all of these cases, remember each component may either Escape the value handled, or escape it only in Logs. Knowing how each component is configured, and how they handle String Literals, UTF-8 multibyte chars and/or Numeric Constants is key!
Consider at least these factors:
a => Sender of Client Cert, how the initial Cert data is formatted
b => Nginx typically uses the exact Cert Subject DN it receives, but it escapes values in its own logs by default unless you override this behavior.
c => App/Upstream (if you send $ssl_client_s_dn in Header) may escape the Header value, or it may leave it untouched and only escape it in Logs like Nginx...
These are fundamental concepts - what about providing a solution to the question?
There is a way to modify the value of the Cert DN set in $ssl_client_s_dn when sending to Upstream if this is desired.
#place in Nginx http block only
map $ssl_client_s_dn $client_dn_fix {
    default $ssl_client_s_dn;
    "L=D'UNCONG\C3\89" "L=D'UNCONGÉ"; #Actual Value you mention
    "L=D'UNCONG\xC3\x89" "hex-constant";
    "L=D'UNCONG\x5CC3\x5C89" "escaped-hex-const";
    "L=D'UNCONGÉ" "original";
    "L=D'UNCONG\x5CxC3\x5Cx89" "double-escaped";
    "~L=D'UNCONG[\x5C]C3[\x5C]89" "regex-cert-escaped";
    "~L=D'UNCONG[\x5C]xC3[\x5C]x89" "regex-hex-escaped";
}

#then add to the Location {} block as appropriate
location /blah {
    ...
    proxy_set_header X-Subject-DN $client_dn_fix;
    ...
}

Log the value of both $client_dn_fix and $ssl_client_s_dn.
When reviewing the Logs you will be able to see the real value of the Certs Subject DN expressed in $ssl_client_s_dn and $client_dn_fix then validates Nginx's view of it.
After reviewing logs to understand the internal operations better,  you may replace values like "hex escape" or "original" with a string like:
"L=D'UNCONGÉ" (UTF-8 Literals) or "L=D'UNCONG\xC3\x89" so that the Upstream will receive the "Expected Value".
There are many possible ways to implement the concepts here, it just depends what you really need.
Edit: OP has confirmed that "L=D'UNCONG\C3\89" appears in Logs when checking value of $ssl_client_s_dn , so the following map is finally useful, note this reduces Key/Values to 2 entries:
#place in Nginx http block only
map $ssl_client_s_dn $client_dn_fix {
    default $ssl_client_s_dn;
    "L=D'UNCONG\C3\89" "L=D'UNCONG\xC3\x89"; #Expected Value
}
# $client_dn_fix now contains the Expected Value as OP requested
# modify this value as desired, could also set with original String Literals like => "L=D'UNCONGÉ" 


Thanks for the clear explanation, As you mentioned the escaping is done in access logs of nginx. I have updated the log format with escape=none and found that the certificate's subject has \C3\89.
The hex encoding is done by openssl it seems .I viewed the certificate's subject using the command
Openssl x509 -noout -subject -in certificate.crt -text
the subject had L=D'UNCONG\C3\89
So, my guess is openssl encodes the subject when non ascii characters are present and it is not done by nginx. Seems like I should look into the certificates format to check if it is the default behavior.

Thanks for confirming my findings and giving feedback! Correct, this is done by SSL, not Nginx. This formatting/behavior is based on RFC. Note my Edit- the Map here can be reduced to useful entries... so that $client_dn_fix can be consumed based on implemenation needs... whether you write additional logic in Nginx or simply carry on with "Expected Value" sent in Header to Upstream... I will edit my answer to show the Map redux.

Thanks for the quick reply. But I don't think using a map will solve my problem because D'UNCONGÉ is just an example, it can be anything based on the user's input. covering all of that using a map is an impossible task.
What i was trying to do is add a user's locality to client cert and then making some files accessible to a certain locality. I have a folder D'UNCONGÉ, the files inside it will be served if client cert had L=D'UNCONGÉ.
Seems like I need to find some other way to do this without client cert

Why can't you use a map to validate on existing Dirs... if $ssl_client_s_dn matches an existing Dir, then clearly that client is allowed, and the result of $client_dn_fix could be used to route them as well, that's a passthru with validation relying on a theoretically existing dependency.

I can't use map because I might encounter many such characters like É. Using map I can't fix all such characters and I want to convert \C3\89 to É in nginx itself to serve the file. Since the map has to be static, I might not be able to use it for all the characters

I started to take the challenge to do this purely with Nginx... but in the real world I'd use Lua to rewrite the string, and inject it finally as a location. If no match, the location will 404, so only those in possession of the correct Cert (like a key) can access. :There are other security issues in that plan, but the basic mechanism works.

Yes, this problem seems much simple with lua, will try it

If you are going to use Nginx as an Application, might I recommend OpenResty which provides Native Nginx (1 behind Stable) and a most useful out-of-the box experience, including iconv module (language support) and a host of other ultimately useful modules that are tuned into an entire production suite. Specializing in it since 2013, it is utterly amazing workbench.

One more thing- depending on your env setup, if you have any backend app at all, use its capability to render the correct system path-as-string and then access it. As the pattern here is Nginx -> App , the advantage of Lua is embedded support so that you can simply regex and replace all relevant symbols, and then immediately apply that as Path. However, nearly any other application you have available on the server can return a response, and then that response can be filtered to trigger rewrite to the correct dir...
